# Spinner text not wrapping (not in the spinner itself but the view)

Tags: java, android, textview, android-spinner

For a project I need to create a spinner with multiselection. The text inside the spinner does wrap perfect but when I exit the spinner the text [(Spinner Text)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auj9n.png) does not wrap and is shown as following: [Spinner view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d5ja.png)

Just to make sure: The spinner selection works great but not when I want to show the selected items in the spinner

How do I fix this?

Spinner adapter:

```
simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.my_spinner);
    simple_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice);
```

Spinner:

```
<nl.project.name.View.MultiSelectionSpinner
        android:theme="@style/myTheme"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:dropDownSelector="@color/backGround"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView11" />
```

Spinner Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:singleLine="false"/>
```

Comment: post your code with question

Comment: What code do you want to see?

Comment: your `Spinner view` where the text is not wrapped

Comment: You need to create a layout with root element a `TextView` and use 
` android:singleLine="false"`

Comment: so like android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item but then with singleline ="false"

Comment: Yes instead of using ` android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` you need to create your custom layout and set android:singleLine="false" on `TextView`

Comment: false is default and i already tried that but didn't work. still get one long string

Comment: check my answer

Comment: if you dont mind try to comment `simple_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(` line and try

Comment: i removed the line but still doesn't wrap. Just to be clear: The spinner selection works great but not when I want to show the selected items in the spinnerview

Comment: yes I understand your problem after the selection text is not wrap

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a layout with root element a `TextView` and use `android:singleLine="false"`

**layout_spinner_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:text="" />
```

And set into Adapter like this

```
simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.layout_spinner_item);
```

Comment: okay did you pass your custom layout inside the Adapter constructor?

Comment: Remove android from `android.R.layout.my_spinner` it should be like `R.layout.my_spinner`

Comment: didn't fix it sadly